# Signature of generic MethodRefs in .NET Profiler API

Tags: c#, .net, instrumentation, clr-profiling-api

I am using the .NET profiler API to do IL rewriting. One of my objectives is to emit the type tokens of called method arguments. However, it gets tricky when it comes to generics. For instance, consider the following snippet.

```cs
class C<T>
{
    public void A(T x) {}
}
class Program
{
    public void F(C<int> l)
    {
        l.A(5);
    }
}
```

Method `F(C<int>)` gets compiled into the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig (null) cil managed 
{
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8
    IL_0000:  nop 
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1 
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.5 
    IL_0003:  callvirt instance void class C`1/*02000002(TypeDef)*/<int32>/*1b000001(TypeSpec)*/::A(!0)/*0a00000d(MemberRef)*/
    IL_0008:  nop 
    IL_0009:  ret 
}
```

Here, the `callvirt` instruction at offset `IL_0003` is MemberRef `0x0a00000d`. My goal now is to get the type token of the only argument of this method. To achieve that, I query the method signature using the `IMetadataImport::GetMemberRefProps` function, then parse it to get the type signatures of method arguments. However, I get the uninstantiated method signature:
`blob 0000001B hasthis System.Void (!0)`

As for me, this is a bit weird, because MethodRef `0x0a00000d` corresponds to the instantiation `C<int>::A(int)`, and the type variable `!0` should be instantiated with `int`.

**Question:**
Is there any way to get the specialized generic method signature in .NET profiler API? In particular, how for the above example to obtain the type `int` of method parameter in result?

Comment: IMetaDataImport is old, .NET 1.0 vintage.  Before generics were added in .NET 2.0.  So they added IMetaDataImport2, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataimport2-getgenericparamprops-method